# Upper bound on modulus of complex number plus a real number

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Is it possible to show that for a complex number $z$ and a real number $a$ that:

$$|z + a| \leq |z| + |a|\cos(\arg(z))$$

I know that:

$$|z + a| = \sqrt{|z|^2 + |a|^2 + 2|z||a|\cos(\arg(z))}$$

Also, the extreme case where $z$ is purely real reduces to the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 1):

In the case where $\cos(\arg(z)) < 0$ and $a < 0$, this is not true. For instance, consider $z = -1$, $a = -1$. Then, $|z + a| = 2$, but $|z| + |a|\cos(\operatorname{arg}(z)) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true in general: square the RHS of your inequality and apply the upper bound: $\cos^2(\theta) \leq 1$ then we can show that in fact:

$$|z| + |a|\cos(\arg(z)) \leq |z + a|$$

which is the opposite of the claimed inequality.